# Set column to different property in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have this 2 classes:

```
public class OrderDetail
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int OrderId {get; set;}
    public virtual Product Product {get; set;}
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Number {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

And I have a DataGridView bound to a binding source which in turn is bound to OrderDetail.

For the Product column, the grid currently displays the text `MyAssembly.Product`.

How can I set that column to display `OrderDetail.Product.Description`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to override the `ToString()` method of the `Product` class?

The issue can be reproduced in a new fresh Console Application.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Product product = new Product
    {
        Id = 1,
        Number = 1,
        Description = "TheFirstProduct",
    };

    OrderDetail detail = new OrderDetail 
    {
        Id = 1,
        OrderId = 1,
        Product = product,
    };

    Console.WriteLine(detail.Product);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The behavior of this code is the same as you report on DataGridView.

> ConsoleApplication1.Product

But, if you overrides `ToString()` method on `Product` class like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Description;
    }
}
```

... then the result of `Console.WriteLine(detail.Product)` may be the expected.

> TheFirstProduct